# is there an opposite function for str() in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

`str()` turns data into strings but is it possible to undo this with a built in function?
exe:

```
str1 = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

is there a function that can turn this into a dictionary?
if not what can I do?

I tried:

```
dict1 = dict(str1)
```

but I only just found out that it's not the way to do it

Comment: See duplicate: use `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: Don't use `str()`, use `json.dumps()`, which you can reverse with `json.loads()`.  The `str()` method isn't designed to be reversible (`eval` will work on it *sometimes* but not always), whereas JSON encoding is specifically designed to be.  (There are other encoding methods, but JSON is a very widely used one and will work great with the type of data you're talking about.  It also happens to look a lot like what you get from `str()` but it's not exactly the same.)

Comment: The "opposite" is called parsing. The two are not inverses; any data structure can be turned into a string, but not every string represents a valid data structure of a given type.

Comment: Consider `datetime.datetime`, which provides the instance method `strftime` to produce a string and the class method `strptime` to parse a string.